Major mistake in my paper on arXiv, counterexample found
I am doing a PhD in an area of mathematics; I uploaded a paper on arXiv a few months back, after finding a mistake last year in an earlier paper of my PhD advisor (a long paper published in a top-tier journal and the error was not in the main theorem of the paper) which my advisor accepted and I was working on fixing it, which my advisor himself encouraged me to do, and he said his impression is that the proof can be recovered.
I tried to construct a seemingly new method which seemed to need a lot of work last year, which my advisor encouraged, but eventually to prove a weaker version of the claim at which point my advisor seemed to lose interest, as I became more interested in the methods. It seemed clear the full claim would be very hard to prove.
However, I myself made a poor error at the end and now the main claim of my arXiv version is wrong, and actually I found a counterexample to the claim of my advisor's co-authored paper (with a different mathematician) and my own current paper with the weaker claim.
However, it may still be that the method I constructed can say something new for a nicer class of objects.
When I was finishing writing this argument (which remained a bit badly written), I emailed my advisor a few times to discuss these ideas and for some help, and he didn't respond. I asked another mathematician about this problem and my advisor's lack of response, and decided to upload to arXiv.
It seemed like I did not have any other meaningful work for several months other than working on this question, which in itself was frustrating to me.
My advisor expressed his displeasure at me having submitted this paper to a journal recently, something I asked him several times earlier about when he didn't reply.  I apologized to him a few weeks back, asking him if I should withdraw the paper which he didn't tell me to do. But just now I found this error.
If I were to upload the counterexample to arXiv, should I first withdraw (indicating the error) and then upload as a revision on the same submission?
Lastly, should this have a bad impact on my reputation?

You seem to be too concerned of your reputation among the math community, but I encourage you to take care of your relationship with your advisor first. It's alright to work on fixing a mistake he made in the past, but involving other researchers and publishing your work in that direction without his consent seems a bit rough to me.

When I see people correct their mistakes, usually my opinion about them improves. So I think your reputation will certainly not suffer from doing this, quite on the contrary. If the mistake can be corrected, just upload a second version of the paper on arXiv, and if the mistake completely invalidates your paper, there is an option to withdraw the paper from arXiv (it will be still accessible, but people will see that it has been withdrawn). This is the best thing a scientist can do, and as long as you make mistakes only in a few of your papers, your reputation will benefit because people will know that they can trust you and your other papers.

The mistake is irretrievable; but I have a counterexample, and will upload that on arXiv on the same link.

People make errors, especially if they are inexperienced. You should minimize the repercussions of the error, though. Knowingly publishing false results can damage your reputation. Also, if the mistake is in a submitted paper, you should talk as soon as possible to the editor about retracting the paper. You can see it as a chance to write a better paper.
You might want to correct the arXiv paper, just so that people are not led astray.
Of course, you did not make the advisor happy by finding an error, but the relationship seems to have survived. It is too bad that you two are not working together on this.

If I understand correctly, the sequence of events is this:

Your advisor published a paper that included a strong claim.
You realized that his paper had problems, so you worked together to try to salvage it.
You eventually managed to prove a weaker version of the claim, and some computational methods, but your advisor lost interest when you gave up on the strong claim.
But you "did not have any other meaningful work for several months," so you kept running with it.
You eventually published this weak proof on arXiv and submitted to a journal, but this angered your advisor for some reason.
You found a problem with your weak proof.

This is clearly not good; this paper is a bust, and it doesn't seem like you have other lines of inquiry where things are going better. Additionally, your advisor does not respond to your messages, does not keep you busy, and is angry with you (and they don't even know yet about this most recent error!). I do not know whether the problem is with you or your advisor or both, but your current way of working does not seem like it's on the right track. I realize this isn't an answer to the question you asked, but it's the answer you need to hear: you should fix your relationship with your advisor, or find a new one. Then you can ask your advisor the other questions.
Anyway, to your actual questions:

Post a single revision to arXiv; no need to retract.
If this hasn't been published for real yet, and the only problem is with the arXiv preprint, then this will do minimal/no damage to your reputation. And as others have said, it reflects well on you that you have the integrity to correct your mistakes rather than just hoping no one notices.
But your goal in graduate school is to get a good reputation with several impressive accomplishments, not merely to avoid getting a bad reputation. You do not currently seem to be on track to achieve this.


Don't worry about the reputation thing. When I did my research, I found errors in the proof of many "leaders of the field" on a routine basis, even in fundamental works that have 10000+ citations and shaped entire fields. Research is more about mistake prevention and correcting past mistakes as best as possible rather than being perfect.
Don't worry about the feeling of your advisor. I bet that they don't even care about their mistake (because not a lot of people in the world care about the research in the first place, let alone being able to spot the mistake.) Normally people just keep these mistakes in their mind and try not to repeat them in future publications.
Don't even bother correcting Arxiv. If anyone else is so seriously interested in your paper, then they will spot your mistake, and then either issue a correction to your paper, or write their own paper without acknowledging yours (while secretly happy that they are right and you are wrong - they will never tell you). If they cited your result and made even more mistake, then this is their mistake for not carefully proof-reading a non-peer reviewed pre-print uploaded to a server hosted by Cornell university.

Is this a serious comment?

@CaptainFoo Yes. From someone who has made mistake before and realized that nothing serious happened and nobody cared. Then later found out that everyone else also made mistakes and nobody cared either.

How can you be a researcher if you don't care about the quality of the work you publish? This needs to be satire.
